# Do bath products need to be certified kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Do bath products like soap and bubble bath need to be kosher? I am particularly asking about Mr. Bubbles bath foam and Lush soaps and Lush bath bombs.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Answer (score 6):

Actually this is not as simple as it looks.

In a [very interesting analysis](https://oukosher.org/blog/kosher-professionals/the-kashrus-of-soaps/), the OU notes this is a dispute and some *poskim* did not approve applying animal-based soaps to one's skin. However in one practice one does not need to worry for two reasons

> 1. *(from OU):* The common custom nowadays is to use permit all soaps, even when containing non-kosher materials . Although there are Gedolei Yisroel,
>      past and present, that are known to have been privately cautious in
>      this area, vigilance from soaps is considered a chumra. **The accepted
>      practice amongst the masses is to use all soaps**.

2. Soaps today (particularly those you mention) are typically not manufactured with animal fats, [Lush](https://uk.lush.com/products/soaps) for instance is officially 100% vegetarian

Comment: I can think of one instance in some modern commercial soaps (shampoos) which would require supervision. In some natural soaps today, they use mixtures that could contain both meat derived products (types of fats) and dairy derived products (actual milk). The prohibition of mixing meat and milk includes even possessing them and benefitting from that mixture (like washing with it).

Comment: This is very interesting. I wonder (but do not know) is animal fat used in a factory has the status of meat. Or is it processed to a level that is not anymore.

Comment: The only areas where I have seen that type of reasoning presented (something is processed to such an extent that it no longer has the status of its original source) is in the context of medicines. In such cases, the rationale is in the relation to the final product providing curative/healing results to sick people. Shampoos generally wouldn't fall under that category. Also, there are many types of non-animal based fats that could be substituted. And since the mixing is being done with intent from the start, it would place the limitation of l'chatechilah conditions on the prohibition.